# sc.hasNextLine() never ends, stuck in loop

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I an trying to write a read method that takes input from key board. but the input is a large text that needs to be analyzed one line at a time.

```
risks = new ArrayList<String>();

    try{
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(in);
        //number of updates
        numberOfUpdates = Integer.parseInt(sc.next());
        //constant cost per bundle
        constantCost = Integer.parseInt(sc.next());
        String line = null;
        while(sc.hasNext()){
            line = sc.nextLine();
            risks.add(line);
        }
        sc.close();

    }         
    catch(NullPointerException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The code never ends unless I use CTRL+Z then it stops and reads the rest of the code, if I dont it stays in an infinite loop, how can I close this automatically.  I thought `line = sc.nextLine();` would do it, but it didn help at all.

Comment: where do you get the input from? a file?

Comment: the input is on a server I think and there is programming running them on my code to check for result I have to pass for all of them.

Answer (score 1):

If we can assume that `in` is `System.in`, your while-loop will never terminate since `System.in` never ends, so to say. Take this quick example:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

while (scanner.hasNext()) { //Never terminates
    System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
}
```

This while loop will never terminate. Instead, try using a keyword to end the loop, eg `"continue"`:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String s;

while(!(s = scanner.nextLine()).equals("continue")) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

This will terminate as soon as the user types in "continue" and assign `nextLine()` to `s`, which can be worked with inside the loop.

So in your case:

```
String s;

while(!(s = scanner.nextLine()).equals("continue")){
    risks.add(s);
}
```

Comment: this cant be done because the code is being checked automatically and it wont press anything like continue or done to stop, it has to be another way.

Comment: So you are looking start the program, paste the text and then automatically continue? I'm not quite getting what you want.

Comment: no its part of my assignment, I am writing an algorithm, it has to accept inputs in a form of a text, this is done automatically to see if my code results are correct with different inputs, this part has nothing to do with my algorithm the loop never ends so unless I press ctz+z it wont stop, do u get it?

Comment: Not really. What do you mean by "it has to accept inputs in a form of a text, this is done automatically"? Does it take input via the console or does it come from a file?

Comment: I am not sure, there is a server I guess deos this once I upload my code, it uses different kind of input to check the result, the problem is my current code it stuks at a loop, it shouldnt be like that it should readall the lines and then stop, do you think maybe I should use input stream reader?

Comment: If even you are not sure how the input is read, how should I be able to help? I can't guess what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Add a condition for stopping, say user inputs "done"

```
while(true){
   line = sc.nextLine();
   if(line.equals("done")
     break;
   risks.add(line);
}
```

Comment: you are right, i hastily wrote the code. modified it, altough i don't like using break. alternative is to assign the string and then compare it with "done" inside the while; answer by other user has this example, won't post the same :)

Comment: this cant be done because the code is being checked automatically and it wont press anything like continue or done to stop, it has to be another way